# Making ticking sounds of different frequencies. Solves problem with alsa and jack by avoiding them

Tags: python-3.x, alsa, jack

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pygame
from array import (array)
from pygame.mixer import (Sound, get_init, pre_init)

class Electrode(Sound):
    SEQUENCE = [
        ['A4', 440.00], ["A#", 466.00], ['B',  493.88], ['C',  523.25],
        ["C#", 554.00], ['D',  587.33], ["D#", 622.00], ['E',  659.25],
        ['F',  698.46], ["F#", 739.00], ['G',  783.99], ["G#", 830.00],
        ['A5', 880.00]
    ]
    N = len(SEQUENCE)
    SCALE={k:v for (k,v) in SEQUENCE}

    def __init__(self, coefficient=0, volume=0.5):
        (self.active, self.duration)  = (True, 3)
        self.coefficient(coefficient)
        Sound.__init__(self, self.build_samples())
        self.set_volume(volume)

    def __call__(self):
        if self.active:
            self.play(self.duration)
        return self

    def coefficient(self, coefficient):
        index = int(min(max(1, coefficient), Electrode.N-1))
        self.key = Electrode.SEQUENCE[index][0]
        self.frequency = Electrode.SCALE[self.key]
        return self

    def set(self, on):
        self.active = True if on else False
        return self

    def build_samples(self):
        period = int(round(get_init()[0] / self.frequency))
        samples = array("h", [0] * period)
        amplitude = 2 ** (abs(get_init()[1]) - 1) - 1
        for time in range(period):
            if time < (period / 2):
                samples[time] = +amplitude
            else:
                samples[time] = -amplitude
        return samples

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from time import sleep
    pre_init(44100, -16, 1, 1024)
    pygame.init()
    for n in range(0,Electrode.N):
        Electrode(n)()
        sleep(1)
```

Comment: I found equivalent utiltiy in pygame without these problems so abandon this question.

Answer (score 0):

Replaced pysine calls with pygame calls.